# JavaScript inside JSF page not getting element by ID for Canvas

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf, canvas

Since it seems impossible to do canvas in JSF by using h5: tags (I found a tutorial but the xmlns address it says to use for h5 is reported as invalid in netbeans) I decided to just use good old html. Problem is that my ctx1 = ct1.getContext("2D") reports that it can't set property of "null" which means that my first line, c1 = document.getElement... is returning null. I don't understand why.

Basically what I'm doing is displaying the number of hits (using cookies) and the user's ip address and the server's time on the page in a canvas. Im using 3 different canvas' because its easier than trying to figure out how to do multi-line canvas.

I know the BEAN's work because I can put them outside the javascript and/or canvas code and it shows the right info. So its something about javascript not being able to get the ID's of the different canvas elements. Any thoughts?

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>User Info</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <br></br>

        <canvas id="hitsCanvas" width="200px" height="50px"></canvas>
        <br></br>
        <canvas id="ipCanvas" width="200px" height="50px"></canvas>
        <br></br>
        <canvas id="timeCanvas" width="200px" height="50px"></canvas>

        <script>
                var c1 = document.getElementById("hitsCanvas");
                var c2 = document.getElementById("ipCanvas");
                var c3 = document.getElementById("timeCanvas");

                var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2D");
                var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2D");
                var ctx3 = c3.getContext("2D");

                ctx1.font = "30px Arial";
                ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
                ctx3.font = "30px Arial";

                ctx1.fillText("Hits:#{CookieBean.getCookie()}");
                ctx2.fillText("IP Address: ${CookieBean.getIP()}");
                ctx3.fillText("IP Address: ${CookieBean.getTime()}");
        </script>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

CookieBean.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Named(value = "CookieBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CookieBean implements Serializable {

    int hits;

    public int getHits() {
        return hits;
    }


    public void setHits(int hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
    }


    public String getCookie() {
        Map<String, Object> requestCookieMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap();
        Cookie hitsCookie = (Cookie)requestCookieMap.get("hits");

        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("maxAge", 31536000);

        if (hitsCookie == null) {
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().addResponseCookie("hits", "1", properties);
           return "1";
        }
        else {
            String newCookieHits = hitsCookie.getValue();
            int intCookie = Integer.parseInt(newCookieHits);
            intCookie++;
            String stringCookies = Integer.toString(intCookie);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().addResponseCookie("hits", stringCookies, properties);

            return stringCookies;
        }
    }

    public String getIP() {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    return ipAddress;
    }

    public CookieBean() {

    }

    public String getTime() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        return timeStamp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here I am cursing JSF and HTML5 and wondering why this stupid code doesnt work and after I submitted this here and also a copy to my tutor (this is homework for university), within about 5 minutes I figured it out.

How? well first I wrote the same code without JSF into a regular HTML page and it still didnt work, so after looking at some w3c examples I found out what the problem was. Changed the following line of code:

```
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2D");
```

to

```
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
```

Yeah...that was pretty much it. I also had to add the x,y values to filltext to position.